# Multiple recipients in a docusign custom Lightining Button?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-lightning

i'm configuring a salesforce button to automatically pull the Docusign Template and populate the recipients with the records in the Salesforce Object. But It doesn't work, the second recpient overwrites the first and it leaves a blank. [Image for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FQVg.png)

```
[SourceID = Contract.Id,
DST = '3eccc558-ebdf-441b-89a3-ebc33c7af577',
CRL = 'Email~' +Contact.Email + ';LastName~' + Contact.Name +';SignInPersonName~'+Contact.Name+';RoutingOrder~1;SignNow~1;Role~Client' + 'Email~' + Opportunity.OwnerEmail + ';LastName~' + Opportunity.OwnerFullName +';SignInPersonName~'+Opportunity.OwnerFullName+';RoutingOrder~2;SignNow~1;Role~Opportunity Owner',
LA = '0',
LF = '0'
]
)
}
```

I have a Previous code that pulls the first recipient just fine, but i don't know what i am missing for the second one, if anyone can enlighten me, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

var sourceId = DSGetPageIDFromHref();

var CRL = 'Email~{!Contact.OwnerEmail};FirstName~{!Contact.OwnerFirstName};LastName~{!Contact.OwnerLastName};Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,Email~{!Contact.Email};FirstName~{!Contact.FirstName};LastName~{!Contact.LastName};Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1';

var CCRM='Signer 1~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2';

var CCTM='Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer';

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID=" + sourceId + "&CRL=" + CRL +
"&CCRM=" + CCRM +
"&CCTM=" + CCTM;

If you are using 6.9.4 you can use URLFOR within your custom buttons. if you have upgraded to DocuSign for Salesforce 7.0+ you can only use URLFOR.

For examples and more information please see the following link:
https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-7-0-This-page-requires-a-CSRF-confirmation-token